# gnome-classic as default session for all users?

Tags: linux, session, gnome, xorg

How to set gnome-classic as default session for all users in gdm3 (system-wide setting)? I'm using Debian Jessie with GNOME 3.12.

I've tried creating fake gnome.session in /etc/xdg/gnome-session/sessions that launches gnome-classic and searched for relevant gdm3 setting but to no avail. Solutions I've found online seem to work only for older GNOME versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
update-alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager \
  gnome-session-classic /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 99
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 90`

Comment: @MasterM: Did either of these work for you?  I'm using CentOS, so `x-session-manager` doesn't seem to apply for me, but was curious nonetheless.  If it did, could you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Debian Wheezy 7.8 with GNOME 3.4.2.
After installing Debian and at the first user login, I could select gnome classic instead of system default login.
After this selection and without any configuration, I am using the gnome classic exclusively.

Comment: Good for you. Now, how do you do it ***for all users*** at once, system-wide?

Comment: Go to /var/lib/AccountsService/users. For my case, I can see Debian-gdm file. It says [User] Language= XSession=. And I can see a file of my user name. It says [User] Language=en_US.utf8 XSession=gnome-fallback. Go to the following link [https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en]

Comment: (1) If you know an answer to the question, put it into your answer. Click on [edit]. (2) Provide a usable answer, not just a link. (3) If you know of link(s) that substantiate your answer and/or provide supplemental information, by all means include them in your answer. But verify them first; the URL you posted in your comment (above) doesn't work.